# Header and Echo dilemma

Tags: php

I have a contact form on a site I'm developing and have written some PHP that will return errors to the page if certain fields aren't filled in correctly, everything works fine, the email sends if it is filled out correctly and if it isn't the right error messages are sent out and displayed.

The only problem is that if the form is filled out incorrectly, the user is redirected to the page with the error message but the form is lower down the page to where the user is redirected. I'd like if there is an error for the user to be redirected to the same page with the error message echoed out, but lower down on the page where the form is.

I did some research and saw I could use id anchors and header, but if I do this the page does load where I tell it to, but the error message doesn't show. I've attempted to use an if loop with a _GET variable to check if it matches something in the error message, but can't seem to get anything working properly.

*So to summarise:

I'd like if the form is filled out incorrectly, for the user to be returned to the same page, but lower down where the form is and for the error message variable set in the code to be displayed above the form.*

I've just started learning PHP so I would appreciate some help with resolving this.
Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

**Here's some screenshots of the site:**
http://imgur.com/a/Hv5OW

**Here's the page's code:**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name    = trim($_POST["name"]);
    $email   = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    if ($name == "" OR $email == "" OR $message == "") {
        $error_message = "You must enter a name, email address and message";
    }

    if (!isset($error_message)) {
        foreach ($_POST as $value) {
            if (stripos($value, 'Content-Type:') !== false) {
                $error_message = "There was a problem with the information you submitted";
            }
        }
    }

    if (!isset($error_message) && $_POST["address"] != "") {
        $error_message = "Your contact form submission has an error";
    }

    require_once("inc/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    if (!isset($error_message) && !$mail->ValidateAddress($email)) {
        $error_message = "You must specify a valid email address";
    }

    if (!isset($error_message)) {
        $email_body = "";
        $email_body = $email_body . "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
        $email_body = $email_body . "Email: " . $email . "<br>";
        $email_body = $email_body . "Message: " . $message;

        $mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
        $address = "name@email.co.uk";
        $mail->AddAddress($address, "Corwen Forestry Timber Products Ltd.");
        $mail->Subject = "Website Contact Form Submission | " . $name;
        $mail->MsgHTML($email_body);

        if ($mail->Send()) {
            header("Location: contact.html?status=thanks");
            exit;
        }
        else {
            $error_message = "There was a problem sending the email: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }
}
;
?>

<?php
$title = "Corwen Forestry Online | Contact Us";
$active = "contact";
include("inc/header.php");
?>
    <img class="banner" src="images/contact-us.jpg" alt="Contact us background image.">

    <article class="band content-wrap clearfix">

        <?php if (isset($_GET["status"]) && $_GET["status"] == "thanks") { ?>
            <section>
                <p class="contact-thanks">Thanks for getting in touch, we'll get back to you as soon as we can.</p>
            </section>
        <?php }
        else { ?>

            <header>
                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            </header>

            <section class="contact-intro">
                <p>
                    Lorizzle hizzle dolor fizzle amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing elizzle. Crackalackin sapien velizzle,
                    my shizz volutpizzle, suscipit quis, its fo rizzle vel, arcu. Pellentesque fizzle tortizzle. Izzle
                    mammasay mammasa mamma oo sa. Fusce izzle dolor dapibus turpis tempizzle tellivizzle. Crunk
                    pellentesque nibh izzle turpizzle. Fo shizzle my nizzle funky fresh crackalackin. Pellentesque
                    eleifend rhoncizzle nisi. In for sure habitasse platea dictumst. Donec dapibizzle. Curabitur gangsta
                    urna, pretizzle eu, pizzle ac, my shizz vitae, nunc. Da bomb suscipizzle. Integer break it down
                    pimpin' shiznit fo shizzle my nizzle.
                </p>
            </section>

            <section id="error-anchor" class="contact-third first">
                <img src="images/contact-icon-email.png" alt="email icon">

                <h3><a href="mailto:sales@corwenforestry.co.uk">sales@corwenforestry.co.uk</a></h3>
            </section>

            <section class="contact-third">
                <img src="images/contact-icon-address.png" alt="address icon">

                <h3>
                    Ty&rsquo;n Llidiart Industrial Estate<br>
                    Corwen<br>
                    Denbighshire<br>
                    LL21 9RZ
                </h3>
            </section>

            <section class="contact-third">
                <img src="images/contact-icon-phone.png" alt="phone icon">

                <h3>01490 412 146</h3>
            </section>

            <?php
            if (isset($error_message)) {
                header("Location: contact.html#error-anchor");
                echo '<p class="error-message">' . $error_message . '</p>';
            }
        ;
            ?>

            <form class="clearfix" method="post" action="contact.html">
                <table class="contact-us">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <label for="name">Name</label>
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <label for="message">Message</label>
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="display: none;">
                        <th>
                            <label for="address">Address</label>
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            <p>Please leave the address field blank, it's an anti-spam measure.</p>
                            <input type="text" name="address" id="address">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
            </form>

            <section class="map">
                <iframe width="47.7%" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
                        src="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=208085933608816427574.0004e1242973ccf3517ee&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=52.977589,-3.414001&amp;spn=0.144707,0.291824&amp;z=11&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
                <br/>
                <small>View <a target="_blank"
                               href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=208085933608816427574.0004e1242973ccf3517ee&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=52.977589,-3.414001&amp;spn=0.144707,0.291824&amp;z=11&amp;source=embed"
                               style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">CFTP HQ and Mills</a> in a larger map
                </small>
            </section>

            <section class="map-key">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/a-sml.png" alt="Head Office map icon key.">
                        Head Office &amp; Shop
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/b-sml.png" alt="Gwyddelwern Sawmill map icon key.">
                        Gwyddelwern Sawmill
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/c-sml.png" alt="Llandrillo Sawmill map icon key.">
                        Llandrillo Sawmill
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>

        <?php } ?>
    </article><!-- end band content-wrap -->

<?php include("inc/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: You say you are redirecting to a certain anchor if the form is incorrect. But that does not show from your code above. Could you update your code?

Comment: @claarman I've added the line "header("Location: contact.html#error-anchor");" where I had it when I was trying to get it to work.

Comment: check my answer, that should work (with a bit of tweaking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i get from your question you can use the following approach:

The idea is to "anchor" the form onSubmit - this allows us to go down to the form despite if form valiadtion were passed successfully or not, right after submit button pushed.

1) Set up an "anchor"-action like this:

```
<form class="clearfix" method="post" action="contact.html#myAnchor">
```

2) Set up a "fake" url right above the form like this:

```
<a href="#myAnchor"></a> 
<form class="clearfix" method="post" action="contact.html#myAnchor">
```

you can style this  in a way you like, **or use id="myAnchor" in the form tag if its not break anything.**

3) Use your current code, at the first glance it looks fine:

```
if (!isset($error_message)) {
   // Send mail
} else {
   // do everything you want with error variable.
}
```

4) Echo the error right above the form

```
<a href="#myAnchor"></a>
<?= $sFormattedErrorVariable ?>
<form class="clearfix" method="post" action="contact.html#myAnchor">
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: I've used this and it works, thanks. I tried to modify it slightly, I want a conditional in the form tag to echo action="contact.html" when the $error_message variable is not set and action="contact.html#error_anchor" when it is set. The thing is I've set it up and it only works on the second erroneous submission not the first. Here's the code I'm using in the form tag <?php if (isset($error_message)) { echo 'action="contact.html#error-anchor"'; }else{ echo 'action="contact.html"'; } ?>

Comment: Oh wait I see why now, when it's initially submitted the form method even if it has got errors is still contact.html, only when the second submit is passed does it have the right action.

Comment: Yep. The approach i proposed makes you code works like. Form Submit -> Error(?) -> If yes - the action acnhor tooks down to the form -> If no -> get out oh here by your `header("Location: contact.html?status=thanks");`, setting up new "clear" page. For more advanced technique read about AJAX -  it allow you to build site with better performance, more flexible and cute ;) . Cheers!

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, thanks dude. My only concern was that regardless of the status of the submission, weather it had any errors or not it still displayed #error-anchor at the end of the URL, but I was overcomplicating it, I just changed the id to #anchor LOL. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want something like this. If you post the form incorrect it should redirect the user to a link like:

```
Header('Location: contact.html?error=' . $error . '#error-anchor');
```

To get this working, you will have to change a couple of things;

**Your form needs an id**

```
<form class="clearfix" method="post" action="contact.html" id="error-anchor">
```

**To keep your url clean you might want to change your error handling**, for example change:

```
if ($name == "" OR $email == "" OR $message == "") {
    $error_message = "You must enter a name, email address and message";
}
```

to

```
if ($name == "" OR $email == "" OR $message == "") {
    $error = 1; //to use in your redirect url
}
```

**Way on top of you page you will need to check if `$_GET['error]` as been set** (to use after the redirect) and set the message accordingly:

```
if ($_GET['error']) {
    switch ($_GET['error']) {
        case 1:
            $error_message = "You must enter a name, email address and message";
            break;
        case 2:
            $error_message = "Other error";
            break;
    }
} else if ($_POST) {
     //form post handling
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, thanks very much, but this is a bit confusing for a novice like me. I might re-visit this at a later date to both figure it out and possibly apply it.

Answer (score -1):

You should create smarter catch errors. Maybe create an array of errors and adds new.
Some like:

```
$error_message = array();
...
// $error_message[ID_MSG]
$error_message[2] = "text of msg";
...
<td>
 <input <?php
  if(isset($error_message[2])) {
   echo 'value="' . $email . '" class="errorStyle"';
  }
 ?> type="text" name="email" id="email">
</td>
...
```

For counting errors use some like:

```
count($error_message) > 0
```

Comment: I'm failing to see how this applies to the question and situation I mentioned above.